# Find if a specific pair of values exist in an array of named objects in localStorage with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

In localStorage I set previously various objects which are stored in this format

```
console.log(localStorage) 
// Outputs the storage this way, it may contain different objects (randid for example)

Storage {
    876346545: "{"ABA":"876346545","ABB":"37578533567","ABC":"AE123456","ABD":"1234567890123456"}", 
    randid: "fhjidc06om230j2r367gh1i5iec", 
    353446545: "{"ABA":"353446545","ΑBB":"12343212341","ΑBC":"CC949590","ABD":"5943949562340543"}", 
    length: 3
}
```

**I try to find if a specific pair exists in this array of objects for example**

```
 //Pseudo-code
 if anyofObject in localStorage contains pair ("ABA":"876346545") return true or false
```

**My code** which does not do what I expect

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage) // I tried and without Parsing it as JSON

for (var key in data) {
    if (data[key].ABA = "876346545") {
        var m = data[key];
        console.log("Found: ", m)
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you stringified the JSON so the value stored is a string, so you can not access its ABA property.

Comment: @DBalazs if I don't stringify is stored like `876346545: "[object Object]"` which is also  a string of words

Comment: @Cadmos, it is not an error to stringify it but then you have to remember to `JSON.parse()` before accessing it as you are trying to do.

Comment: You can do `localStorage.indexOf('"ABA":"876346545"') > -1`. Unless you need other values, its pointless to parse JSON. You can achieve it using string operation as well

Comment: `JSON.parse()` should be called inside the `for` loop for each `data[key]`. Otherwise, `data[key]` is a string so it can't have a `ABA` key itself

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go through all the values stores in your local storage. You will have to do the following:

1. Get all the values using `Object.values`, and start filtering them one by one
2. Try to parse them as JSON object, some will fail because they are not JSON object, those are not of our interest
3. Those that parsed successfully, you need to check the key and see if the value for that key matches properly as in matches in type as well as value. Return true so that we can be done with our search and the value is stored in a variable.

Also, please note when you are comparing values use `===` and not `=` in your if statements as you have shown in your question. Also, take care types when comparing. You are setting ABA as a number but you are trying to compare with a string.

```
userData = {
  "ABA": 876346545, 
  "ABB": 37578533567, 
  "ABC": "AE123456", 
  "ABD": 1234567890123456
};

localStorage.setItem("Some Random Key", JSON.stringify(userData));

// This will find the object and store it in foundObject variable
const foundObject = Object.values(localStorage).find(v => { 
  try { 
    return JSON.parse(v).ABA === 876346545; 
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(foundObject));

// This will find the object and store true if found, false if not found in hasObject variable
const hasObject = Object.values(localStorage).some(v => { 
  try { 
    return JSON.parse(v).ABA === 876346545; 
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(hasObject));
```

Comment: I don't search to find it in userData, I tried to find it amongst objects I added in localStorage, see my second block on my question

Comment: `undefined` applying it to the localStorage object which is as in my first block in post `Storage { .... }`

Comment: If you run my code block in your browser's console, it does what is expected.

Comment: The value is stored in foundObject variable. You can console.log it and see the result. Please rerun the code now. I have added a console.log

Comment: Yes I've seen it through console.log and I made it to output true/error within the conditional loop, however when pair of values is found shouldn't the loop stop? No matter what, the `catch(e)` block keeps returning value and does not stop the loop of further searhing. Neither `break;` works on try block.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the stored object in the localStorage, because it is stored as a string.

```js
for (var key in localStorage) {
  try {
    const value = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
    if (value.ABA == "876346545") {
       var m = localStorage[key];
       console.log("Found: ", m)
       break;
    }
  } catch(e) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: if not found > `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0`

Comment: I edited my answer, if you store data other than stringified objects you can not parse them, so you have to wrap it in a `try-catch` block.